# Функция не возвращает значение через return

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция shuffle должна вернуть индекс элемента в массиве (который = 'Крести'), но на чтобы я не менял в return возвращается `<function shuffle at 0x7fd7fb514bf8>`

```
packofCards = ['Черви','Пика','Крести']



def shuffle(packofCards):
    for i in range(3):
        if packofCards[i] == 'Крести':
            return i

print(shuffle)
```

Comment: эту функцию уже написали создатели Python: `packofCards.index('Крести')`

Comment: Мне необходимо это сделать без использования встроенных методов

Comment: тогда при вызове функции не забывайте указывать круглые скобки и передать аргумент функции: `print(shuffle(packofCards))`

Comment: @AlexeyIstomin добавил ответ ниже

Comment: @danilshik, спасибо, я увидел. Приму его, как пройдет ограничение в 10 минут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
packofCards = ['Черви','Пика','Крести']

def shuffle(packofCards):
    for index, item in enumerate(packofCards):
        if item == 'Крести':
            return index

print(shuffle(packofCards))
```